# The mirror_ticks function not working for ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to place ticks on all four sides of my graph. The way suggested for this is `mirror_ticks`.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggplotTicks)

sp6<-ggplot(Anna_Smooth, aes(y=log10(Prob2), x=log10(AvSize)))+
  geom_point( data=Anna_Smooth, aes(y=log10(Prob2), x=log10(AvSize), color=PART) )+ 
  guides( color=FALSE)


sp8<-sp6+ labs(x=expression(paste(log(s))))+
  labs(y=expression(paste(log(P(s))))   )+
  theme(axis.text.y   = element_text(size=14),
        axis.text.x   = element_text(size=14),
        axis.title.y  = element_text(size=15),
        axis.title.x = element_text(size=15),
        panel.background = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"),
        panel.border = element_rect(colour = "black", fill=NA, size=2)
)


sp10<-mirror_ticks(sp10, allPanels=TRUE)
```

My output sp10 has no ticks on  opposite panels, same result if I put `allPanels=TRUE`
[image]

Is there a fix? I am open to learn how one does this with theme settings?

Comment: There is no `ggplotTicks` package on CRAN. I suppose you are referring to `https://github.com/infotroph/ggplotTicks`? This package hasn't been updated on github since 2016. Perhaps, it doesn't play well with the latest versions of `ggplot2`. Which version of `ggplot2` are you using?

Comment: I guess it is so.. do you know how to use theme settings to achieve this task?

Answer (score 2):

As of `ggplot2` version 2.2.0 (2016-11-11), the `scale_x_continuous()` and `scale_y_continuous()` can display a secondary axis which is positioned opposite to the primary axis and which can be controlled with the `sec.axis` argument.

This can be used to mirror the tick marks.

The OP hasn't provided reproducible data so we use the `mpg` dataset which comes with the `ggplot2` package:

#### Chart without mirrored tick marks

```
library(ggplot2)
g1 <- ggplot(mpg, aes(log10(displ), log10(hwy))) +
  geom_point() +
  theme(
    axis.text.y   = element_text(size = 14),
    axis.text.x   = element_text(size = 14),
    axis.title.y  = element_text(size = 15),
    axis.title.x  = element_text(size = 15),
    panel.background = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
    axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"),
    panel.border = element_rect(
      colour = "black",
      fill = NA,
      size = 2
    )
  ) 
g1
```

[image]

#### Chart with secondary axes

```
g1 + 
  scale_x_continuous(sec.axis = dup_axis()) + 
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = dup_axis())
```

[image]

```
g1 + 
  scale_x_continuous(sec.axis = dup_axis(name = NULL)) + 
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = dup_axis(name = NULL))
```

[image]

```
g1 + 
  scale_x_continuous(sec.axis = dup_axis(name = NULL, labels = NULL)) + 
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = dup_axis(name = NULL, labels = NULL))
```

[image]

#### Mirrored tick marks with log10 scales

The secondary axes are also available with the `scale_x_log10()` and `scale_x_log10()` functions.

So, it can be avoided to use  the `log()` function within the call to `aes()` but by specifying an appropriate log scale:

```
ggplot(mpg, aes(displ, hwy)) +
  geom_point() +
  theme(
    axis.text.y   = element_text(size = 14),
    axis.text.x   = element_text(size = 14),
    axis.title.y  = element_text(size = 15),
    axis.title.x = element_text(size = 15),
    panel.background = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
    axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"),
    panel.border = element_rect(
      colour = "black",
      fill = NA,
      size = 2
    )
  ) +
  scale_x_log10(sec.axis = dup_axis(name = NULL, labels = NULL)) + 
  scale_y_log10(sec.axis = dup_axis(name = NULL, labels = NULL))
```

[image]